# How can I trace a SQL query generated by EF back to the code that created it

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem with some slow running queries that we only see in production, and I can see the poorly performing SQL in the profiler, however, I don't know how I can use this to trace back to the code that generated the statement in the first place, or if tracing back to the EF query is even possible. Does EF have any ability to identify the origin of the SQL statement to help trace down the problem in the code?

I believe this issue might be related to the code loading loading pessimistically, i.e. its loading an entire results set and then filtering a list in the code rather than filtering it in the SQL

Comment: Have you considered purchasing http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof.  Read http://ayende.com/blog/169155/nhibernate-entity-framework-profiler-3-0

Comment: with entity framework 6 you should be able to [log it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx). But an easier way (which I use) is just put breakpoints for the queries that are most suspectible. You should know which table are mapped to which entity, correct?

Comment: Man, I'm gonna be thinking about this one all day...  If I could vote this question up again, I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, in your Repository or DataContext (common place where query is executing) to debug write every query.

```
 var data= from item in entity
                 where item.id = 564564
                 select item;    
 Debug.WriteLine(((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)data).ToTraceString());
```

You can write following code to say what is the call stack when above query was executed. Then find the query you looking for and call stack will tell you where the query was executed.

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
```

You can use microsoft tracing or log4net to log this stuff and then easily find your query.

Comment: I think he means making the resulting SQL query identifiable to its original EF/C# code.

Comment: well I thought he can keep tracing these queries, and then match it with the profile queries. I will edit..

Answer (score 5):

Old thread, but you could implement a `DbCommandInterceptor` that builds a stack trace and adds it to the SQL command as a comment.  This would couple the C# function that made the call with the EF SQL in the profiler and in Azure.

Something like this should do it:

```
public class QueryOriginInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private const string _sqlCommentToken = "--";
    private const string stackLoggerStartTag = _sqlCommentToken + " Stack:";

    private bool _shouldLog = false;

    public static string StackLoggerStartTag => stackLoggerStartTag;

    public QueryOriginInterceptor(bool shouldLog = true)
    {
        _shouldLog = shouldLog;
    }

    void AppendStackTraceToSqlCommand(DbCommand command)
    {
        if (!_shouldLog)
            return;

        int positionOfExistingCommentStartTag = command.CommandText.IndexOf(stackLoggerStartTag);

        if (positionOfExistingCommentStartTag < 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> frames = (new StackTrace())
                .GetFrames()
                .ToList()
                .Select(f => $"{f?.GetMethod()?.ReflectedType?.FullName ?? "[unknown]"}.{f?.GetMethod()?.Name}")
                .Where(l => !l.StartsWith("System.") && !l.StartsWith(this.GetType().FullName));

            string comment = $"{stackLoggerStartTag}{Environment.NewLine}{_sqlCommentToken} {string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}{_sqlCommentToken} ", frames)}{Environment.NewLine}";
            command.CommandText = $"{Environment.NewLine}{comment}{command.CommandText}";
        }
    }

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) => AppendStackTraceToSqlCommand(command);

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) => AppendStackTraceToSqlCommand(command);

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) => AppendStackTraceToSqlCommand(command);

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) { }

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) { }

    void IDbCommandInterceptor.ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) { }
}
```

Then in your DbContext constructor, you add it as an interceptor:

```
DbInterception.Add(new QueryOriginInterceptor());
```

In the profiler, you'd see the query being executed like so:

```
-- Stack:
-- YourApp.Users.GetUser
SELECT
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID],
    FROM [dbo].[User]
WHERE [Extend1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
```

There are some considerations with this approach, such as the performance hit of building the stack trace, and there might be multiple execution plans cached if the same function is called from different locations.

Comment: What a great solution!! Made my day

Comment: WATCH OUT - the suggested method will cause EF to add a new intereceptor to the interecptor chain. This means that on the first time you construct a data context you will have one interecptor. On the second time you will have 2, and so on. This will (obviously) cause a significant performance degradation over time.  In short - make sure you remove the added interepctor after each use, or don't use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another entity in your database (ie: DebugEntity) and run a query on it right before/after the actual queries.

```
ctx.DebugEntity.Where(x => x.ID == "myId1"); //myId2, myId3, myId4, whatever helps you locate the LINQ query from the profiler...
```

This should show up in SQL profiler.